# How to Add 3 images to each row of a UITableView?

Tags: uiview, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a collection of images that the number of them aren't determined and vary from 0 to 1000, anyone got an idea how can I present them to the user? I think I can add each three of them to a uitableviewcell but I don't know how. any help would greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

theres:

UITableView.backgroundView

and

UITableView.contentView

afaik you should be able to `addSubview:yourImage` to those...